# How to list all files in a hard disk with 'find'?

Tags: bash, find, ls

I'd like to list all the files in HDD including size, last modified date and absolute path.

idea format :

```
[file size] [last modified date] [absolute path] [ filename]
```

I tried:

```
ls -lhR | awk -v PWD=$PWD '{printf("%4s %4s %2s %5s %s/%s\n", $5, $6, $7, $8, PWD, $9); }' >> /tmp/report.list
```

It worked perfectly until it hit some files/directories with space in-between.... So I tried:

```
find . -name "*" -exec du -sh {} \; -exec date -r {} \; -exec echo " " \; >> /tmp/report.list
```

But the output seems spread into 3 lines instead of 2, also the printed path is not the absolute path to the file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find`'s `-printf` action to output those attributes directly e.g.

```
find "$PWD" -printf '%s\t%Tx\t%h\t%P\n'
```

- `%s`: File's size in bytes.
- `%Tx`: File's last modification time, in locale's date representation
- `%h`: Leading directories of file's name
- `%P`: File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.

The directory path (`%h`) is printed relative to the command-line path argument with which the `find` command is invoked: by specifying the working directory using `$PWD`, it becomes absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-printf` option in find:

```
find / -type "f" -printf "%s\t%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%p\n" > file.txt
```

This makes a file with format:

[size in bytes]TAB[Last modified date in YYYY-mm-dd format]TAB[FULLPATH]

It will run on the full file structure.

Replace each `\t` with a space if you don't want it tab delimited. Using `man find` you can find other format options for the `-printf` option in `find`.

Comment: Thanks, however, it print in bytes. some of my files are Gigabytes large.  what I did now (kind of clumsy) is: find . -not -path '*/\.*' -type f \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec du -sh {} \; -exec date -r {} \; > /tmp/find.list
awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1' /tmp/find.list >> /tmp/report.list

Comment: @MartinWang If this is your answer, than you should write an answer. =)